# Find how close number is to 0.5

Tags: math, glsl

When given a number between 0.0 and 1.0, I want to find how close this is to 0.5.

Here is an example. Left is input, right is expected output.

```
0.0 => 0.0
0.1 => 0.2
0.2 => 0.4
0.3 => 0.6
0.4 => 0.8
0.5 => 1.0
0.6 => 0.8 
0.7 => 0.6
0.8 => 0.4
0.9 => 0.2
1.0 => 0.0
```

How can I achieve this without using an if statement?

I currently have this, it works for numbers 0.5 and below, but not above.

```
var x = 0.2;

console.log(x * (1 / 0.5));
```

Comment: How is this related to [tag:gls]l? GLSL is the [OpenGL Shading Language](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_Shading_Language)

Comment: Trying to do some rgb math while writing a shader

Comment: `var x = 0.2;` and `console.log(x * (1 / 0.5));` is not glsl

Comment: Yeah sorry, it's just easier to debug the maths in javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `1 - 2 * abs(number - 0.5)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the if statement by using Math.abs which give you the absolute value of your operation. You can look at the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#i0) for more informations.

To be able to use this method you will need to import it from the *Math* library like that:

```
import java.lang.Math.abs;
```

Comment: `abs` is builtin in GLSL -- not that java libraries are at all relevant here.